# Show Google Ads/AdMob in .NET MAUI

Tags: admob, maui, .net-maui

I am quite aware that .NET MAUI is just the next generation implementation of Xamarin.Forms, so most Xamarin.Forms guides should work on .NET MAUI (I guess).

Has anyone got Admob to work in .NET MAUI, and if so, how?
I just need pointing in the right direction and I will be on my way

Comment: It seems that there is no an AdMob library for .NET that is compatible with .NET MAUI at this time. All the third-party libraries need to be made compatible with .NET MAUI and this might take some time.

Comment: do you have any update for this topic? The `MauiMTAdmob` doesn't work well

Comment: Coudn't find anything. It really doesn't work well.

Answer (score 4):

The plugin for MAUI version is available for some time now.
See below link for details.
https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob

Comment: I have noticed that it's not working for me, simply installing the Nuget is throwing a lot of errors

Comment: It works for my app.  You can read the tutorial to setup your project. https://www.mauiexpert.it/admob-for-maui-made-easy/

Comment: The previous versions of MAUI have been on .net6, the released version is .net7. All these libraries are based in .net6. Looks like we're all waiting until the libraries catch up.